# Howcan I prevent blur in far-away textures?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am starting to learn Unity 3D, I've never done anything with it and I know almost nothing. I don't even know how to ask this question properly, so any insights on things I should study to understand this problem are also very welcome.

Here is the problem:

I have a simple scene: a few cubes, and a light source. The cubes have a texture (just a white square with a black border) on them, I created a material for the cubes and set the texture as its albedo. But no matter what I do with the light, it creates various zones of illumination (please see the print screen).

In the screen you can see 4 zones:

- Iluminated zone: this is where the light hits directly, the cubes are white with a clear black border on its edged
- Shadow zone 1: the border on the cubes are still clear, but the cubes have a blueish color
- Shadow zone 2: the borders on the cubes start to get blurred
- shadow zone 3: the borders are even more blurred

As I zoom in the shadow zone 1 gets bigger, and as I zoom out it gets smaller, so I suspect that the camera might be causing this, not the light, or it might be a problem with my texture / material...

What I want is for everything to look like the illuminated zone, or at least the shadow zone 1. How can I accomplish that?

[image: print screen]

Comment: Try setting your cube's texture to use anisotropic filtering

Comment: @Ruzihm thanks for the tip, I think that's the right path. Do you know where I change the filtering? In the texture's inspector, when I try to change the value of filter mode it only has 3 options: "Point(no filter)", "Bilinear" and "Trilinear". So I didn't change the filtering. However, there is a setting called "Aniso Level" that was in 1 and I changed it to 16. It greatly improved the quality, but it still gets blurred as it gets further away from the camera, is there anything I can do to eliminate this blurring completely?

Comment: If you must have no blurring, try turning off the **Generate Mip Maps** option, then click on the **Apply** button. This will prevent blurring but will consume extra compute power to render the texture.

Comment: That's it, thanks a lot! If you post this as answer I'll mark it as the accepted. If it is not too much to ask: do you know roughly how much extra computing power does it consume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must have no blurring, try turning off the Generate Mip Maps option, then click on the Apply button. This will prevent blurring but will consume extra compute power to render the texture.

Comment: thanks! as you suggested in the comments I also set the aniso level to 16

Answer (score 1):

Turning Off Mip Maps will solve the issue but will cost extra computation the optimal solution would be aniso level to 16.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for me I turned down the fade length and it worked perfectly

Comment: Instead of providing the answer directly, try writing a comment explaining the solution if it's not too lengthy, @kyl.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).